# Want to add image to aspx rss page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rss, xmltextwriter

I have a cod where my `aspx.cs` file writes to an aspx the xml tags.

Now I have a requirement where I need to add logo at the end of the 'title' tag.

this is my code,

```
  writer.WriteStartDocument();
  writer.WriteStartElement("rss");
  writer.WriteAttributeString("version", "2.0");
  writer.WriteStartElement("channel");
  writer.WriteElementString("title", "FRA News");
  writer.WriteElementString("link", fraNews);
  writer.WriteElementString("description", "FRALatest actions");
```

When this is displayed as an rss feed I want the logo at the right corner of the 'Title' field. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
writer.WriteStartElement("image");
writer.WriteElementString("url","http://www.fileparade.com/Images/logo88x31.png");
```

Comment: @ coder thanks, but after adding these 2 lines,my main tags, item.title/link/desciption is not seen...just when i uncomment i can see them. any guesses?

Comment: I think due to the start element try to remove it and check if it worked.

Comment: the image one.If it still continues have a look at this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53067/Create-an-RSS-Feed-in-ASP-NET